# In Redshift SQL query for reducing years

Tags: amazon-redshift, spark-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

i have data with fields as shown below

| id | grade | grade_id | year | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 5 | 7 | 2022 | 9 |
| 105 | k | 2 | 2021 | 2 |
| 106 | 4 | 6 | 2020 | 5 |
| 110 | pk | 1 | 2022 | 1 |

i want to insert records for same id until we reaches grade = pk , Like shown below for every record in the table .

| id | grade | grade_id | year | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 5 | 7 | 2022 | 9 |
| 101 | 4 | 6 | 2021 | 8 |
| 101 | 3 | 5 | 2020 | 7 |
| 101 | 2 | 4 | 2019 | 6 |
| 101 | 1 | 3 | 2018 | 5 |
| 101 | k | 2 | 2017 | 4 |
| 101 | pk | 1 | 2016 | 3 |

need help in sql code

Comment: We can't help you with your sql code unless you include it

Comment: which one i need to include it .. i didn't get you ..

Comment: Your SQL, the one that you need help with. Not more tables of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table amish.cte_test
(id int, 
grade int,
year int,
diff int)

insert into amish.cte_test
values (101,5,2022,9)

with recursive temp1( id, grade, year, diff) as
(select id, grade  , year , diff  from amish.cte_test
union all
select id, grade-1, year-1,diff-1 from temp1
where grade-1 > -2) 
select * from temp1
```

Comment: Thanks Amish,  i have 100 of records like given in the input table . how can i run for all the records in the table to get the output .. Please help me

Comment: in our input table , grade is defined as varying char .. but u have taken int .. so we r getting conversion error . Could you plz help us

Comment: in recursive cte you have to join cte table with main table with id , for your 100 ids.  also grade needs to be int or convert it to int as we are reducing its value. Provide sample data and table structure ifyou still need help.

Comment: sir amish, i have edit the input and output table now .. please help me .. i was able to get records when the grade is int but in my db system grade is varying char .